Нормально ли на практике писать такие классы express js
захотел как в nest js кастомные исключения написать , но не знаю делают так или нет на практике , есть ли смысл


import { Response } from "express"; 
 
enum TypeOfException { 
  ERROR = "error", 
  MESSAGE = "message" 
} 
 
export class Exception { 
  type: TypeOfException; 
  message: string; 
  code: number; 
  data?: any; 
 
  constructor( 
    code: number, 
    message: string, 
    type: TypeOfException, 
    data?: any 
  ) { 
    this.type = type; 
    this.message = message; 
    this.code = code; 
    this.data = data; 
  } 
 
  exception(res: Response) { 
    return res 
      .status(this.code) 
      .json({ [this.type]: this.message, data: this.data }); 
  } 
} 
 
export class BadRequestException extends Exception { 
  constructor(message: string) { 
    super(400, message, TypeOfException.ERROR); 
  } 
} 
 
export class UnauthorizedException extends Exception { 
  constructor(message: string) { 
    super(401, message, TypeOfException.ERROR); 
  } 
} 
 
export class CreatedSuccessfullyException extends Exception { 
  constructor(message: string, data?: any) { 
    super(201, message, TypeOfException.MESSAGE, data); 
  } 
} 
 
export class OkayException extends Exception { 
  constructor(message: string) { 
    super(200, message, TypeOfException.MESSAGE); 
  } 
} 
 
export class InternalServerException extends Exception { 
  constructor(message: string) { 
    super(500, message, TypeOfException.ERROR); 
  } 
}
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express"; 
import { Exception } from "../utils/Exceptions";  
 

//middleware
export function errorHandler( 
  err: any, 
  req: Request, 
  res: Response, 
  next: NextFunction 
) { 
  if (err instanceof Exception) { 
    return err.exception(res); 
  } 
 
  return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" }); 
}
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"; 
import { prisma } from "../../../prisma/prisma.client"; 
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"; 
import { 
  BadRequestException, 
  CreatedSuccessfullyException, 
  InternalServerException 
} from "../../utils/Exceptions"; 
 

//controller
class UserController { 
  async register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { 
    const { email, password, name } = req.body; 
 
    if (!email || !password || !name) { 
      return next(new BadRequestException("Все поля обязательны")); 
    } 
 
    try { 
      const existUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({ 
        where: { 
          email 
        } 
      }); 
 
      if (existUser) { 
        return next(new BadRequestException("Пользователь уже существует")); 
      } 
 
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5); 
 
      const user = await prisma.user.create({ 
        data: { 
          email, 
          password: hashedPassword, 
          name 
        } 
      }); 
 
      return next( 
        new CreatedSuccessfullyException("Пользователь успешно создан") 
      ); 
    } catch (error: any) { 
      console.log(error); 
      return next( 
        new InternalServerException("Ошибка при создании пользователя") 
      ); 
    } 
  } 
 
  async login(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { 
    const { email, password } = req.body; 
 
    if (!email || !password) { 
      return next(new BadRequestException("Все поля обязательны")); 
    } 
  } 
} 
 
export default new UserController();




OkayException выглядит довольно странно :)

ну я долго не думал над именем. сама задумка не бредовая слишком? (в бэкенде не особо силен пока)

нужно выбрать либо Okay либо Exception - это по сути противоположности. Твой класс Exception на самом деле скорее Response. С помощью этого класса ты формируешь ответ сервера

спасибо, поменяю название
